# Is it possible to set up an Exception handler in an init file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

Suppose you have an existing app, and want to modify the exception handling for the entire app. It is not possible to wrap the app in a `begin/rescue` block.

What is a good way to modify the exception handler (to suppress the backtrace) by adding code that runs before the app starts?

Comment: was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

begin/rescue are not methods so you can't over-write them. If an exception is raised, several steps will unfold, the first one being...calling .exception on whatever object you passed the exception on. Example:

```
class A
  def exception
    p 'I am going to print'
    RuntimeError.new('message')
  end
end

a = A.new
raise a #=> 'I am going to print' and then runtime error is raised
```

If you control what you pass to 'raise', then you can pass it an object. The first step after .raise is called is that it calls the `.exception` method on that object, as you can see from here.

If you don't want the backtrace to show at all in the terminal, use abort instead of raise:

```
abort 'aborting!' #=> prints 'aborting' to STDERR and then does exit 1 implicitly. No backtrace is shown.
```

You can wrap the entire app in a method that will do all the exception handling for you:

```
def exception_handler
  puts 'Do whatever you want here before the app starts executing'
  yield
rescue
  # put the logic of handling errors here
  # for example, you could do 'abort 'error occured'' that will make the program stop and not show a backtrace
end

exception_handler do
  puts 'My app code goes here'
end
```

Will print:

```
Do whatever you want here before the app starts executing
My app code goes here
```

Let's say your app raises a bunch of ArgumentErrors. What you can do is re-open the class and execute some code before raising:

```
class ArgumentError
  alias_method :real_initialize, :initialize
  def initialize(*args) # we're overriding initialize
    super(*args)
    p 'some code here'
  end
end

raise ArgumentError
```